# Prevent RecyclerView in BottomSheet from rendering offscreen views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

Reproducible sample project on github: [recyclerview-bottomsheet-not-recycling](https://github.com/znakeeye/recyclerview-bottomsheet-not-recycling)

On `Android` it is common to have a draggable bottomsheet. For any scrollable content, `RecyclerView` is a great candidate. However, when put inside a bottomsheet, recycling/virtualization does not occur for the items that *would* have been visible if the bottomsheet was fully expanded. This implies a significant performance hit for no apparent reason. I.e. views are inflated and the `onDraw()` method is called. I believe tons of BottomSheet featured apps silently suffer from this. There ought to be a solution to this non-performant behavior.

Google issue exists: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180537056

**How can you configure/tweak [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView) or its [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager) to prevent invisible bottomsheet items from being rendered?** Please avoid `ViewStub` solutions. Let's focus on the root of the problem - the `RecyclerView`.

### Illustration

E.g. If the height of the main layout is 1000px and the *invisible* `RecyclerView` has items with a height of 200px, then five views will be immediately created and rendered:

| My App |
| --- |
| Main View (1000px) |
| Collapsed bottom sheet |
| Item 1 rendered Item 2 rendered Item 3 rendered Item 4 rendered Item 5 rendered Item 6 NOT rendered Item 7 NOT rendered ... |

And a screenshot from the sample app on github. Here a bunch of items below the screen have been rendered - even though they are invisible.

[image: Sample app]

### The relevant part of the layout

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
   android:id="@+id/layout_retainer"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/black">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:clipToPadding="false"
       android:background="@color/white"
       app:behavior_hideable="false"
       app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
       app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
       android:adapter="@{adapter}" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```